# Handling database results that include the '\n' escape sequence

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I insert this into the database from a textarea:

```
Hello

How 

Are 

You
```

It gets saved like so:

```
Hello\n\nHow \n\nAre \n\nYou
```

But when I display it in the textarea after putting it through `nl2br` it still shows up as `Hello\n\nHow \n\nAre \n\nYou`.  How do I make it display the same way that I had inserted it into the database?

This is the jQuery code I am using to get the value:

```
           var getURL = WEBROOT + "index.php/Connection/getConfig/" + rowID;
                    var editConfig = $("<div>");
                    editConfig.load(getURL, function(){
                        var configValue = $(this).html();
                        console.log(configValue);
                        var button = $("<button>", {
                                html: "submit"
                            }),
                            textArea = $("<textarea>",{
                                width: "350px", height: "600px"
                            }).val(nl2br(configValue));
                        $(this).text("").append(
                            textArea,
                            $("<br/>"),
                            button
                        ).dialog({
                            title: "Editing Config for id " + rowID,
                            modal: true,
                            width: 405
                        });
                  });
```

Comment: It sounds like you stored the character sequence `\n` in your database rather than an actual newline as represented by that escape code.  Can you confirm?  In that case [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) is not going to make any difference - you need to use [`stripcslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php) instead.  However, I'd recommend fixing the data in your database so that its contents are not escaped.

Comment: @eggyal THANK YOU! that worked! please make answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

It sounds like you stored the character sequence `\n` in your database rather than an actual newline as represented by that escape code. In that case [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) is not going to make any difference (it replaces actual line breaks with HTML `<br/>` tags, which isn't even what you want in order to display line breaks in a `<textarea>`) - you need to use [`stripcslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php) instead.

However, I'd recommend fixing the data in your database so that its contents are not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot format the text in a text area. You can use a div instead. Use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace the "\n"

Comment: But it is still showing as `Hello\n\nHow \n\nAre \n\nYou ` the php script is returning the wrong thing!

Comment: you can replace the \n in the output using str_replace

Comment: That is what more or less nl2br does btw!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the correct way of doing things, but you could always replace the `\n` with `<br>` using `str_replace` before storing it in the table. You then just have to output the message and all will be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

nl2br turns line breaks into br html tags and you cant render html in textarea only in a div. If you want to display text with line breaks you would be better of using Tiny-Mce http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php it makes things like this easy

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you used `echo nl2br($var)` to display inside textarea. Reason is, if you had done that then the `\r\n` would have become `<br/>` and you would be seeing

```
Hello<br/>How <br/>Are <br/>You
```

Use the following code to display inside textarea:

```
echo $var
```

Use the following code to display outside textarea i.e. inside a table cell or DIV etc.

```
echo nl2br($var)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put this in a new HTML file:

```
<form>
<textarea>
abc
def
123
</textarea>
</form>
```

To get the line breaks into the textarea, `<br>` should not be used - but a hard-return instead.  Have you PHP script output the `"\n"` to the browser and see what happens.

Comment: @Neal Try removing `nl2br` everywhere.